# Is it "I slipped through the cracks" or "I fell through the cracks"?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, idiomatic-language

One of my friends said to me:

> *"You have such a good job though."*

And I responded by saying:

> *"I slipped through the cracks."*

I was trying to imply that my interviewers went easy on me. He corrected me and said it is:

> *"I **fell** through the cracks."*

Is he right?

Comment: Have you looked them up in a [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/fall-slip-through-the-cracks)? They're essentially the same.

Comment: I looked it up online and I found that they are the same. But "fell through the cracks" somehows sounds better to me than "slipped through the cracks". And even my friend pointed out that fell through the cracks is correct. So I wanted to see if actually one of them is more appropriate then the other.

Comment: Both of them mean the same thing. Which one sounds better is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: This is not the most usual context for either phrase: both usually imply that something was forgotten because it (metaphorically) fell between the planks of a floor.  But if you extend the idiom, I prefer “slipped”, which suggests evading, over “fell”, which is usually a misfortune.